# FFMPEG overlay filter at specific time/frame

Tags: video, filter, ffmpeg, overlay

I'm trying to insert an overlay video into another one at a specific time or frame. For that purpose i'm using this command:

`ffmpeg -y -i INPUT1 -i INPUT2 -filter_complex \"overlay=enable='between(t,1,2)'\" -c:v prores OUTPUT`

The problem is that when playing the resulting file, the overlay plays fine and at the time requested, but the main video gets freezed in the first frame and the whole video is chopped.

Comment: Share full log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the same output file as an input. Solved